# Statement of Well-ordering principle

Tags: elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers, well-orders

The statement of well ordering principle appears in different mode - on subsets of natural numbers, or well-ordering of every (non-empty) set. For the question below, I am considering it w.r.t. non-empty subsets of natural numbers.

The question below appeared in my mind, and I was unable to justify myself by referring various articles/books. It started from proof of Division Algorithm.

> *Let $a>b>0$ be integers. Then there are (unique) integers $q$ and $r$ such that $a=bq+r$ where $0\le r<q$.*

> **Proof:** Consider $S=\{ a-bn \,\,| \,\, n\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}, \,\, a-bn\ge 0\}.$ Then $S$ is non-empty (since $a\in S$) subset of $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$; by well-ordering principle, it contains least element, say $r=a-bq$. ..... [the rest of the proof goes for  proving that $r$ satisfy above conditions.]

**Question.** Since $S$ is finite set,  do we really need well-ordering principle in proof of Division Algorithm? To make more precise, let us make two statements.

i) A non-empty finite subset of $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ contains least element.

ii) A non-empty infinite subset of $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ contains least element.

So, in statement of well-ordering principle, do we need to include both i) and ii)?

(The inclusion of i) and ii) in well-ordering principle is done simply by ignoring the words finite/infinite in these statements.)

I was feeling that only ii) is the main part of Well-ordering principle, whereas i) also holds if $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ is replaced by $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ or by $\mathbb{R}$. But, I am unable to clarify my doubts.

Can  anyone clarify my doubts?

Comment: There are two different theorems: The Well-Ordering Principle usually refers to the theorem (equivalent to the Axiom of Choice) that every nonempty set has a well-ordering. There is a separate result, sometimes called "Well-Ordering Principle for $\mathbb{N}$", equivalent to the principle of mathematical induction, that simply says  that $\mathbb{N}$, with its usual order, is well-ordered.

Comment: Both (i) and (ii) are important. (i) tells you that the ordering is *total*:  given any $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, at least one of $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$ must hold. (ii) tells you something about the nature of the order (no infinite descending chains, among other things). Saying that one is "the main part"  doesn't really cover it: you need both.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, are the "Well-Ordering Principle for $\mathbb{N}$" and induction equivalent, or is induction stronger? I had read that induction implied the well-ordering principle, but not the converse, given only the other Peano axioms.

Comment: @Joe: The Peano axios are the five axioms that Landau mentions in Foundations of Analysis? (I mean, only these, or some modification in them?)

Comment: @Joe: One has to be careful about exactly what your assumptions are; the first four Peano axioms plus induction imply that $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered. The first four Peano Axioms plus well-ordering do not quite give you induction: you also need an extra statement, something like "every $x\in\mathbb{N}$ is either $0$ or a successor". The first four Peano axioms plus well-ordering only defines limit ordinals. I take the first four to be (i) $0\in\mathbb{N}$; (ii) if $x\in\mathbb{N}$ then $s(x)\in\mathbb{N}$; (iii) if $s(x)=s(y)$ then $x=y$; and (iv) For all $x$, $s(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: @Arturo: I am getting some insight into your comments (especially, last one); can you suggest a reference for discussion of this?

Comment: If you order by absolute value, you get it true for infinite sets using  absolute value ...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee, for which infinite sets?

Comment: $0,-1,1,-2,2,-3,3,\ldots$